# Linq query for unmatched items

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework

I have an application that has a number of uploaded files. I'm trying to quickly locate orphaned files that have not been asociated with any record for deletion to free up disk space.

I have created this method but it's choking on my (poor) linq.

Can anyone see what i've done wrong??

```
public static IQueryable GetOrphanedFiles(int skip = 0, int take = 100)
{
    using (var ctx = new CS3Entities())
    {
        var files = (from f in ctx.Files
                     select new
                                {
                                    FileID = f.ID
                                });


        var links = (from l in ctx.FileLinks
                     group l by l.FileID
                     into g
                     select new
                                {
                                    FileID = g.Key
                                });

        var orhpans = links.Where(f => files.Contains(f.FileID)); <-- dies here

        return orhpans.Skip(skip).Take(take);
    }
}
```

Comment: what exactly do you mean with dies here? an exception?

Comment: it doesn't compile: Compiler Error Message: CS1928: 'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable.Contains<TSource>(System.Linq.ParallelQuery<TSource>, TSource)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: what did SQL profiler show.   even more interesting the Debug value of f=> files.Contains(f.FileID))   Did that generate a Expression tree that is too big for EF to send to SQLServer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change as follows:

```
var orhpans = links.Where(f => files.Select(x => x.FileID).Contains(f.FileID));
```

Comment: @GordonCopestake Is your original query correct? To me it looks like it is returning non orphaned fileIds?

Comment: +1 ,yeah, hard to post a corrected linq statement when the original is hard to follow.  Seems @Magnus understood what he wanted to do.

Comment: Yeah to be honest Magnus solved the problem but my logic was wrong to start with. Ended up with this instead: var orphans = files.Except(links); Much easier!